# Grouping user interface logic into a sort of UIService?

Tags: java, architecture, domain-driven-design

Being accustomed to using services and the concise calls they provide to interfact with the business layer, I've been wondering if this approach can be applied to the user interface.

For example, in a Swing application I often find myself adding a bit of logic to handle different actions. If this was programmed against an interface this would separate the actual handling from the presentation and perhaps make code clearer to read.

So, could an extra layer be applied for this purpose? Knowing that MVC is most often applied to UIs it seems that an interesting parallel could be made with the idea of a controller.

Comment: Where do you add your logic? Swing is already doing a lot with interfaces, i.e. EventListeners. You could easily add them up into one Facade to handle all the actions of a specific domain. Or you inject a very high-level service into those listeners, but this sounds like you would need a lot of very specific services, I do not know if it helps the domain

Comment: The application logic itself can be found in domain service classes. The logic mentionned here is specific to the UI which in turn forwards calls to the service domain layer. What I do currently is either leave the handling code inside a component (messy) or extract it inside an `AsbtractAction` class.

Comment: (Continued) The issue with leaving code is that there is no clear separation between the handling and presentation like in this [implementation of MVC](http://www.emilmont.net/doku.php?id=java:design_patterns:model_view_controller). What got me thinking of an extra layer is that some architectures have other types of layers (Application, Infrastructure...) and a layer like this could sit above the service domain layer. The idea would be to extract the implementation so either me or another developer could swap around/enhance the code. A facade of some sort would certainly fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) has a very clear approach for its html gui. Most components there have an own component model. In fact this results in many little controllers for each component which makes them really easier to maintain than most other structures I've seen. Your idea of a new layer seems to be a quite similar idea.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Might be mistaken but the mention of many controllers reminds me of the HMVC (see this [diagram](http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/). The idea is discussed in this [Javaworld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2000/jw-0721-hmvc.html) (if anyone finds the source please let me know). Will check it out :)

Comment: @James Poulson Very nice articles you shared there! I didnt even remember the HMVC anymore. Last time I encountered it was when I investigated into a C# project where it had a simple background to allow an eaysier exchange of window form components to WPF based components. Personally I think for web projects it is crap. I never encountered a redesign of a page without a redesign of its semantics, so the controllers are affected always the same way. Instead I like a thin presentation layer the at most on top. Thats what your idea seems to be, too. Wicket in my opinion does this job quite good.